# Convert file with multiple name-multiple value pairs to Rows shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am working on changing a file which has multiple name value pairs with both spaces and commas.

My input file has Server name, Version number & zones (A,B,C,D)
A server can be part of multiple zones.

My input file is like this.

```
  Servername1  3.0 A,B,C,D
  Servername2  3.0 A
  Servername3  3.0 B
  Servername4  1.0 B,C
```

I want to convert my input file like the below. If my server is part of multiple zones, I have to create a seperate entry for it prefixing the server name and version to it.

```
  Servername1  3.0 A
  Servername1  3.0 B
  Servername1  3.0 C
  Servername1  3.0 D
  Servername2  3.0 A
  Servername3  3.0 B
  Servername4  1.0 B
  Servername4  1.0 C
```

Can you please suggest?

Comment: Welcome. Could you make your question more explicit, e.g. "Is there any way to do it with a shell script  using standard shell tools like 'sed', 'awk', etc.?" It would also be helpful to know the OS used (Linux, OS X, ...) and the shell you are using (bash, zsh, csh, ...). Both things are important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case you use `awk` on a file where:

- a field separator exists (here: the default space).
- one column has values separated by another delimiter (here: comma).
- and you want to treat these values as if they were fields (here: A,B,C,D)

then you can use the [split()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function. It splits a string into an array using a separator. Ather that you can access these values as array elements, starting from `a[1]`.

```
awk '{ split($3,a,","); for (i=1;i<=length(a);i++) {$3=a[i]; print} }' file
```

output:

```
Servername1 3.0 A
Servername1 3.0 B
Servername1 3.0 C
Servername1 3.0 D
Servername2 3.0 A
Servername3 3.0 B
Servername4 1.0 B
Servername4 1.0 C
```

Comment: In case you can have no third field, you could do this: `awk '{if (NF>2) {split($3,a,","); for (i=1;i<=length(a);i++) { $3=a[i]; print}} else {print}}' file`. I think its self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^((.* )[^,]*),/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

Replace the front of the list by itself, a newline and the front of the list less the part that changes. Print/delete the front of the list and repeat.